# Pagination with vanilla javascript and dots

Tags: javascript, pagination

i have a pagination in javascript and i want to add steps with dots in that pagination.
Taking as an example, the photo, i want dots after three pages and before the last three pages.

1 2 3...10 11 12

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5iYs.png)

I have a var pagesize and total items. The pagination is created the first time when ajax call is on success

```
// how many items per page
var pageSize = 20;
// initial page to display (first page MUST be 1 and not 0)
var pageNo = 1;
var paginationButtons;
```

---

```
            success: function(data) {
            var data = JSON.parse(data);
            var content = '';

            if ( data.errors || data.info.total < 1) {
                content = displayEmpty();
            } else {
                // generate pagination list only when this function is called for the first time
                if (initialFetch) {
                    var totalItems = data.info.total;
                    var totalPages = calculateTotalPages(totalItems, pageSize);
                    generatePaginationList(totalPages); 
                }

                content = displayResults(data.my_data);
            }
            table.innerHTML = content;
        }
```

I calculate total pages like that

```
function calculateTotalPages(totalItems, pageSize) {
    return Math.ceil(totalItems/pageSize);
}
```

And i have that generation of pagination on my page

```
function generatePaginationList(totalPages) {
    const paginationWrapper = document.querySelector('#pagination-wrapper');
    const list = document.createElement('ul');
    list.className = 'pagination';

    for(i = 0; i < totalPages; i++) {

        var listItem = document.createElement('li');
        var listItemButton = document.createElement('button');
        var listItemButtonText = document.createTextNode(i+1);

        // set the page defined in pageNo as active by default
        if (i == pageNo-1) listItemButton.className = 'active-page';
        
        listItemButton.appendChild(listItemButtonText);
        listItem.appendChild(listItemButton);
        list.appendChild(listItem);
    }

    paginationWrapper.appendChild(list);
    paginationButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.pagination li button');

    paginationButtons.forEach(btn => {
        btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
            // unset previous active-page button
            document.querySelector('.active-page').classList.remove('active-page');

            this.classList.add('active-page');
            fetchData(pageSize, this.innerText, false,date_from,date_to); //ajax call on every change of pagination
        });
    });
}
```

Thank you.
Regards,
George

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would do. If you don't understand, let me know.

Basically, there are cases for every amount of pages, with the dots `...` as placeholders.

```js
let pageNo = 1;
const pageWrapper = document.querySelector('.pages');
const input = document.querySelector('input[type=number]');

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', generatePagination);

function generatePagination() {
  let pages, count = +input.value;

  if (pageNo > count) pageNo = count;

  if (count >= 15) pages = [1, 2, 3, '...', Math.ceil(count / 2), Math.ceil(count / 2) + 1, '...', count - 2, count - 1, count];
  else if (count >= 8) pages = [1, 2, 3, '...', Math.ceil(count / 2), '...', count - 1, count];
  else if (count > 5) pages = [1, 2, 3, '...', count];
  else pages = new Array(count).fill(0).map((_, i) => ++i);

  pageWrapper.innerHTML = '';
  pages.forEach(page => {
    if (page == '...') pageWrapper.innerHTML += page;
    else {
      const button = Object.assign(document.createElement('div'), {
        className: 'button',
        innerText: page
      });

      pageWrapper.append(button);
      if (page == pageNo) button.classList.add('active');
    }
  });
}

addEventListener('click', e => {
  const button = e.target;
  if (!button.classList.contains('button')) return;

  document.querySelector('.button.active').classList.remove('active');
  button.classList.add('active');
  pageNo = button.innerText;
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  gap: 1rem;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.pages {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  gap: .25rem;
}

.button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  background-color: #388697;
  color: white;
  padding: .5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}

.active.button,
.button:hover {
  color: #388697;
  border: 2px solid #388697;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="pages"></div>
<input type="number" value="12">
<button class="btn">Create Pagination</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Seems not to be working. The pagesize is the variable that declares how many items the table has. Not the pages. Sorry if if there was a misunderstanding.

The page number is the active page.

Is there any way to edit the above code to have this result?

Comment: @gioiliop, i have edited my answer, check if it suites what you want